# $\Bbb{R}[x]/\langle(x+1)(x^2+1)\rangle$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb{R}\times\Bbb{R}\times\Bbb{R}$

Tags: ring-theory, ring-isomorphism

How to show these to rings are isomorphic?

My approach:
$$\Bbb{R}[x]/\langle(x+1)(x^2+1)\rangle = \{ax^2+ bx + c + \langle(x+1)(x^2+1)\rangle\mid a,b,c \in\Bbb{R}\}$$

I take $f : \Bbb{R}[x]/\langle(x+1)(x^2+1)\rangle \to  \Bbb{R}\times\Bbb{R}\times\Bbb{R}$,

$$f(ax^2+ bx + c + \langle(x+1)(x^2+1)\rangle) = (a,b,c)$$

Now I can't get the multiplication operation right. Everything else is satisfied, i.e. addition, well-definedness, bijection.

Comment: I don't think they are isomorphic. The Chinese Remainder Theorem says that your ring is isomorphic to
$$\Bbb{R}[x]/\langle x+1\rangle\oplus \Bbb{R}[x]/\langle x^2+1\rangle.$$ The first factor is $\Bbb{R}$ all right, but you should recognize the latter as something else.

Comment: They aren’t. It is isomorphic to $\mathbb R\times \mathbb C.$ Both are algebras of dimension $3$ over $\mathbb R,$ but this one does not have a vector basis of idempotents.

Comment: The proposed isomorphism is a bit too naive. An isomorphism must send zero divisors to zero divisors. Constant terms in $\Bbb R[x]/((x+1)(x^2+1))$ aren't zero divisors, yet you try to send them to $(0,0,c)$.

Comment: John, have you done examples like $$\Bbb{R}[x]/\langle x^2-1\rangle\simeq\Bbb{R}\times\Bbb{R}?$$
Or even $\Bbb{Z}_{10}\simeq \Bbb{Z}_2\times\Bbb{Z}_5$? Those give a better idea of what to expect as opposed to wishfully thinking that the first isomorphism of vector spaces will fit. This is a bit more delicate.

Comment: There are times similar where the quotient is isomorphic to $\mathbb R^3.$ For example, if you had $p(x)=(x+1)(x^2-4)$ in your quotient, rather than $q(x)=(x+1)(x^2+1).$ But even then, your proposed isomorphism wouldn’t work. Rather, $$a(x)+\langle p(x)\rangle \mapsto (a(-1),a(-2),a(2))$$ would be the correct isomorphism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your isomorphism won’t work even for $q(x)$ where $\mathbb R[x]/\langle q(x)\rangle \cong \mathbb R^3.$

For example, if $q(x)=(x+1)(x^2-4),$ you get an isomorphism with $\mathbb R^3$ with the map:

$$f(x)+\langle q(x)\rangle\mapsto (f(-1),f(-2),f(2))$$

or
$$ax^2+bx+c+\langle q(x)\rangle\mapsto (a-b+c,4a-2b+c,4a+2b+c)$$

Note that $-1,-2,2$ are exactly the roots of $q(x).$

For $p(x)=(x+1)(x^2+1),$ we don’t have three real roots. Since $p(x)$ has roots $-1,i,-i,$ e might naively try a similar map to $\mathbb R\times \mathbb C^2$:

$$f(x)+\langle p(x)\rangle \mapsto (f(-1),f(i),f(-i))$$ But the thing is, since $f$ is a real polynomial, $f(-i)$ is just the complex conjugate of $f(i).$ In particular, since conjugation is an automorphism on $\mathbb C,$ one of the copies of $\mathbb C$ is redundant.

The final isomorphism with $\mathbb R\times\mathbb C$ is;

$$f(x)+\langle p(x)\rangle \mapsto (f(-1),f(i))$$

or:

$$ax^2+bx+c+\langle p(x)\rangle\mapsto (a-b+c,c-a+bi)$$

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. :)

Comment: dear @john_cena_420, welcome to the site! :) if you found Thomas Andrews' answer helpful, you may want to consider "[accepting](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/how-do-i-accept-an-answer)" it by ticking the green checkmark to its left. this is a way of both thanking the answerer for their time and effort and getting the question off the "unanswered" queue